# Client send message server not received message in tcp/ip socket program

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, tcp

TCP/IP socket program client send text server receive and store database table. I'm righting code below but i have error text reeving time.

### This is Client Side Code

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.IO;


    namespace ClientApplication
    {
        class Client
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                try
                {
                    TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

                    //tcpclnt.Connect("162.144.85.232", 8080);
                    tcpclnt.Connect("162.144.85.232", 4489);


                    Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                    Console.Write("Enter the string to be Sent : ");

                    String str = Console.ReadLine();
                    Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

                    ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);
                    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
                   Console.WriteLine("Sending.....");

                    stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

                    byte[] bb = new byte[100];
                    int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);

                    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                        Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));

                    Console.ReadLine();

                    tcpclnt.Close();
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
    }
    }
```

### This Is Server Side Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ServerApplication
{
    class Server
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                IPAddress ipadd = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.7");
                TcpListener list = new TcpListener(ipadd, 8080);
                list.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 8080...");
                Console.WriteLine("The Local End point Is:" + list.LocalEndpoint);
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
                Socket s = list.AcceptSocket();
                Console.WriteLine("Connections Accepted from:" + s.RemoteEndPoint);
                byte[] b = new byte[100];
                int k = s.Receive(b);
                Console.WriteLine("Recived...");
                for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));
                ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The String Was Recived throw Server"));
                Console.WriteLine("\n Sent Acknowlegment");
                s.Close();
                list.Stop();


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);

            }

        }
}
}
```

I'm trying to execute this code i have error happen like this 
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. Please resolve my issue .

Comment: What is the exception **message**?

Comment: Hii CodeCaster this is my error message .An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll Thanks

Comment: You need to supply more information. The exception contains this information. Please try to debug the issue. What is the InnerException? Also, your code catches an `SocketException` while you receive a `IOException`, which isn't present in the inheritance chain of `SocketException`.

Comment: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host in. when send text from client to server

Comment: Then the error is in the client and not in the code you've shown.

Comment: i will post client and server code . my requirement is client send text server receive and store database table using tcp/ip socket ipaddress and port number

Comment: Your `while (true)` doesn't make sense, trying to wrap multiple `NetworkStream`s around the same socket. Perhaps this is not the cause of _this_ issue, then it will be the cause of the next.

Comment: Please all are once check above i'm editing my posting question. please give me your thoughts. Thanks one and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems with the code you posted, but the one directly causing the behavior you're seeing is that the server closes the socket without waiting for the client to finish reading from the connection.

Look up "TCP graceful shutdown" for more information. In the meantime, the following is an improvement on the code you posted and won't have that problem:

**Server code:**

```
class Server
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpListener list = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8080);
            list.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 8080...");
            Console.WriteLine("The Local End point Is:" + list.LocalEndpoint);
            Socket s = list.AcceptSocket();
            Console.WriteLine("Connections Accepted from:" + s.RemoteEndPoint);
            byte[] b = new byte[100];
            int k;
            while ((k = s.Receive(b)) > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Recived...");
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b, 0, k));
                s.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("The String Was Recived throw Server"));
                Console.WriteLine("\n Sent Acknowlegment");
            }
            s.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            s.Close();
            list.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

**Client code:**

```
class Client
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

            tcpclnt.Connect("192.168.1.7", 8080);

            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            Console.Write("Enter the string to be Sent : ");

            String str = Console.ReadLine();
            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            byte[] ba = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
            Console.WriteLine("Sending.....");

            stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
            tcpclnt.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);

            byte[] bb = new byte[100];
            int k;

            while ((k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100)) > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bb, 0, k));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

            tcpclnt.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The key thing here is that both server and client continue to read from the connection until the remote end has, by calling `Socket.Shutdown()`, signaled that there is no more data to be read.

I also removed the use of the `System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue` property, which had no effect in this code. That only affects programs that use the `ServicePoint` class and is not useful here.

It's also not clear to me why for the client you use the `NetworkStream` instead of just getting the `Client` socket and using it directly. The `NetworkStream` object is useful when wrapping your I/O in e.g. `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`, but here you're just using `Stream.Read()` and `Stream.Write()`, which have the exact same semantics as `Socket.Receive()` and `Socket.Send()`, respectively. In any case, note that while you are using the `NetworkStream` object for the send and receive, you still need to access the underlying `Socket` instance directly to correctly initiate the graceful shutdown (the endpoint not initiating could just close the `NetworkStream`, since it doesn't have to shutdown until it's done both sending and receiving).

I also cleaned up the handling of the ASCII-encoded text a bit.

Comment: Hi Peter Thank you for giving replay but i have exception error after sending text some time. Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. i have exception above like can u have idea please solution.Thanks

Comment: Sorry. Not only is that a completely different question, that's more likely to be an underlying network transport issue than incorrect usage of the `Socket` API. Note two important pieces of information: 1) the new error happens _after_ you have successfully managed to exercise the code, and 2) it's a failure to _connect_. Typically this happens if the server is simply not running, or if a firewall is blocking access, or a NAT router isn't forwarding traffic for the port, or...well, there are a lot of reasons. I do hope that the above at least got your immediate question resolved.

Comment: Thank You Peter now data receive successfully from client to server, but after how can i insert in database table client sending text in console application, can u have any idea please text me. thanks

Comment: Hi...I'm glad you were able to get the program working. As far as saving received data to a database, I'm not really a database expert. You will get much better advice if you present that question as an actual SO question, especially if you are careful to word it in a specific, answerable way. That way, more people will have access to it, and the question doesn't have to be constrained to the space of a comment. :)

Comment: Okay .How can i set receive message from different client's to and one single server. like above program how can i set multiple clients.

Comment: Please do not use the comments as a way to ask new questions. It does not fit the StackOverflow model, and the comments do not provide a good way either to present a question or to answer one. Just ask a new question, taking care to present it as precisely and completely as you can.